# Django: How do I get referenced objects in a symmetric ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've created a Many-to-Many relationship for the model `UserProfile`, to enable users to grant access to a particular feature to one another. The relationship works as expected with the use of `symmetrical=False` to ensure a user access is one-way.

**Model**

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', default="default_thumbnail.jpg")
    department = models.ForeignKey(DepartmentModel, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    allow_booking_access = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True, symmetrical=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class UserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'UserAccounts'


class UserAccount(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserInline,)
```

I am able to query the users that a particular user wants to grant access to via: *(for example id=1)*

```py
UserProfile.objects.get(id=1).allow_booking_access.all()
```

However, I would like to retrieve the users that have granted access to the particular user.

How would I do this?

**Additional Information**

[Using Relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKBJD.png)
[Database Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiYBh.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
UserProfile.objects.filter(allow_booking_access=my_user)
```

With your sample data, it will return the `UserProfile` with `id=7` for this query.

or if you want to query in reverse:

```
UserProfile.objects.filter(userprofile=my_user)
```

With your sample data, it will return the `UserProfile`s with `id=7`, `id=3`, `user=4` and `user=7` for this query.

Comment: I've attempted the above query and it appears to return 3 instances of the *`my_user`* user. Please refer to my updated question at the bottom. For example for user_id=1 I'd expect to return a query set with just user_id=7. Thankyou

Comment: @Lewis try adding a `.distinct()` at the last (A join can often produce duplicates). Or this query would also work `my_user_profile.userprofile_set.all()` you can change `userprofile_set` by setting the `related_name`.

Comment: @Lewis: hi, I understood the question incorrectly, now it should work (with the first fragment), and the second one to query the relation in reverse.